# Assembly language reading in integers

Tags: assembly, integer

I have to write a program that will read in four integers, do a couple computations and print out the result. I've gotten a result out but I also need to print out the integers that were used and I can't figure out how to do that. No looping can be used. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Prompt  BYTE    "Please enter four integers on different lines: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
Result  BYTE    "The sum of the integers is: ", 0
Num1    DWORD   ?
Num2    DWORD   ?
Num3    DWORD   ?
Num4    DWORD   ?
Sum     DWORD   ?

.code

   main PROC
call Clrscr

mov  edx,OFFSET Prompt
call WriteString

call ReadInt
mov Num1, eax
call ReadInt
mov Num2, eax
call ReadInt
mov Num3, eax
call ReadInt
mov Num4, eax

mov eax, Num1
sub eax, Num2
add eax, Num3
sub eax, Num4


mov Sum, eax

call Clrscr

mov eax, OFFSET Num1
call WriteInt


mov edx, OFFSET Result
call WriteString

mov eax, Sum
call WriteInt

call CRLF


exit
main ENDP
```

Comment: When printing the `Sum` you `mov eax, Sum`, but when printing `Num1`, you've got the `OFFSET` keyword in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov eax, Num1
sub eax, Num2
add eax, Num3
sub eax, Num4
```

If it is the sum that you need then I don't see why you used the SUB instruction twice here!

```
mov eax, OFFSET Num1
call WriteInt
```

To output the first number simply drop the OFFSET tag. Now you display the address of the Num1 variable.
To output all integers that were used without using a loop just repeat the operation for each number. You might want to output a CRLF between the numbers for readability.

```
mov eax,Num1
call WriteInt
call CRLF
mov eax,Num2
call WriteInt
call CRLF
mov eax,Num3
call WriteInt
call CRLF
mov eax,Num4
call WriteInt
call CRLF
```